# parsing a character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, parsing

I read a file containing polynomial functions and have stored them into an array of character arrays. The point of the code is to take the derivative of the functions and display them. My plan of action is to split the individual terms of the functions into their own array so i can easily take the derivative and then put the arrays together to have the final derivative. I need help in making something that will split the individual terms of the function (I don't know how many terms an equation might have either).so whenever a '+' or '-' is read i make whatever is before the operator its own array if that makes sense. below are some equations that are possible equations that will be read from the file.Thanks

```
-2x^2+2x-3

-2x+sinx-3

-x+sin2x-tanx
```

I asked the question earlier on how i should complete the task. They suggested using parsing. I tried hard into implementing their suggestions but didn't get  anywhere.

Comment: i mad that post. they gave me the suggestion of parsing. but i struggled implementing the reasoning by myself ):

Comment: But didn't one of the answers have some code?

Comment: i didn't understand it at all, he was using material i haven't learned yet like structures /:

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a multi-dimensional array and use `strtok()` to split the array using a delimiter, for instance

```
strtok(String, "+-");
```

Comment: I thought "-+" had to be in the string for it to token it. so it would only work if an equation was adding a negative number?